# how to reducing hexa length in java

Tags: java, hex, reduce

I want to ask, I have a hexa numbers in a string such as "ABBCA" with length = 5,
whether the hex numbers can be reduced again to length in 3 or 4, and the reduced numbers that could be restored as the original state into a length 5. if could you please tell me the algorithm or source in java. Thank you in advance, sorry if my english is not good

Comment: convert the base 16 number into base 64. For 4 * 5 = 20 bits of information base 64 needs 4 characters. If you use a higher base like 128, you only need 3 bytes.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I did not think with base64